# javascript function not called on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am using jquery for desktop and mobile version of my website. In desktop version everything is pretty good. Problem is with the mobile version.

I am using jquery change event with select tag for sorting my product list:

```
$('select.sort').change(function(){
    // my code
});
```

This is working on Desktop version, but not on inbuilt browsers of mobiles. However, firefox android version is working with this code.

I tried to play few tricks for mobile version. I write a simple javascript function:

```
function sortList(){
    alert('List will sort');
}
```

I remove the jquery, instead used onchange event in select tag itself, like:

```
<select class='sort' onchange='sortList()'>
    // Option Tags
</select> // Not working

<select class='sort' onchange='alert("Fire")'>
    // Option Tags
</select> // Working
```

The first statement not doing anything when I am using a user-defined function 'sortList'. But the second statement is working when I am using a built-in function 'alert'. I have tested this on different android smartphones like Samsung Galaxy J, Vivo, HTC, Sony, etc. All are having the same problem.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Or is it because may be mobile browsers are not compatible with javascript or jquery.

Comment: Any test env present??

Comment: open richamart.com on your mobile browser. I am still working on it.

Comment: `sortList = function (){   alert('a'); };` Can you try this format once.. instead of function sortList(){};

Comment: Thanks but solved in different way. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was regarding keyword **let**. **let** is a is a non-standard keyword, so I replaced **let** with **var**, old fashion way. Working like charm now. Thanks all of you.